# how do i keep only required elements in an XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, filter, transformation

I have a below given input xml in which i would like to **copy** the element **event:business** and
**event:Order** but only **common:AddList** and **common:Date** under the event:Order and not all of the elements into my final xml

Input XML:-

```
<event:Event>
   <event:EventDetails>

      <event:Order>
          <common:Date>2021-01-19T13:15:40.526Z</common:Date>

          <common:AddList>
            <common:AddData content="blah blah" key="blahblah"/>
            <common:AddData content="blah blah" key="blahblah"/>
          </common:AddList>

         <data:User>
              <data:Key>1</data:Key>
         </data:User>

     </event:Order>

     <event:business>
         <common:Legacy>
                <common:TA>1</common:TA>
         </common:Legacy>
     </event:business>

   </event:EventDetails>
</event:Event>
```

I was able to copy event:business successfully and also whole of event:Order using the below XSLT code . But it does not serve my usecase as I actually need to handpick only few elements like  common:AddList and common:Date under event:Order. What is the best way to do that ?

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns="http://www.example.com/ns#"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>

     <xsl:template match="event:EventDetails" xmlns:event="blah blah">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="event:business" xmlns:event="blah blah"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="event:Order" xmlns:common="blah blah"/>  
        </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>
     
     
      <xsl:template match="@*|node()" >    
                                         <xsl:copy>      
                                          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>    
                                           </xsl:copy>   
                                       </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML Output expected :-

```
<event:Event>
   <event:EventDetails>

      <event:Order>
          <common:Date>2021-01-19T13:15:40.526Z</common:Date>

          <common:AddList>
            <common:AddData content="blah blah" key="blahblah"/>
            <common:AddData content="blah blah" key="blahblah"/>
          </common:AddList>

     </event:Order>

     <event:business>
         <common:Legacy>
                <common:TA>1</common:TA>
         </common:Legacy>
     </event:business>

   </event:EventDetails>
</event:Event>
```

Comment: The XML is using namespace prefixes: **event** and **common**. It looks like that you are missing namespace declarations for them.

Answer (score 1):

Use the identity transformation you have

```
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()" >    
                                     <xsl:copy>      
                                      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>    
                                       </xsl:copy>   
                                   </xsl:template>
```

as the starting point, then block the elements you don't need with e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="event:Order/*[not(self::common:Date | self::common:AddList)]"/>
```